# Modifying icon popout in KML file

Tags: icons, kml, google-earth

I have a KML file that is imported into Google Earth for viewing.  I have the icons designated to a certain icon and color, however when I move my mouse over a group of icons the expanded icons are the default yellow pushpin.  Is there a way to set the color and style of these expanded icons?

Current KML Icon section:

```
<IconStyle>
     <color>FF808080</color>
     <Icon>
        <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/track.png</href>
     </Icon>
</IconStyle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [StyleMap](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#stylemap) and defining the highlight icon.